# Behave feature русский язык

Tags: python, selenium

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет!

Пишу свой первый фича файл в behave/python. Вот мой код

```
   # language: ru
Функционал: Поисковик в Яндекс Маркете

  Сценарий: Телевизоры jvc, sony

    Дано Выполнен переход на сайт 'https://yandex.ru/'
    Тогда Выполнен переход в Яндекс 'Маркет'
    И Выбран раздел 'Электроника'
    И Выбран тип 'Телевизоры'
    И Выполнено нажатие на кнопку "Все фильтры"
    И Установлена цена от '29000' до '30000' рублей
```

Когда я генерирую методы под эти шаги, ожидаю увидеть аргументы переданные в скобках в фича файле (как на приведенной картинке с cucumbera), но они не передаются и не подсвечиваются. Почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сгенерировать шаги, и в этих шагах на месте аргументов добавить фигурные скобки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]